# Azure Function Isolated with QueueOutput and InitialVisibilityDelay

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

Prior to **Isolated** Azure Functions, one could create an **Output binding queue** like so:
`[Queue(...)] CloudQueue outputQueue`

Then, we could add a new message with the ability to add a Visibility Delay like so:

```
var cloudQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage("some message");
var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

outputQueue.AddMessage(cloudQueueMessage, initialVisibilityDelay: timespan);
```

Now that we've migrated these Azure Function to the **Isolated** mode, how does one add a Visibility Delay to the message?

Here's an example from Microsoft's website
[image]

How can we add a Visibility Delay to the message using the **Isolated** mode

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings), explains why I can't achieve what I was able to do prior to Isolated mode. Isolated mode does not take advantage of those rich binding classes.

[image]

What I ended up doing was adding my own **QueueClient** and injecting it in my **[Function]**

[image]

- At (1) I inject the **QueueClient**
- At (2) I read the config file (local.settings.json) and then pass the value into an extension method to validate and/or set a fallback value. I then proceed to call the **SendMessageAsync()** with my message and with my visibility delay.
- At (3) is the extension method (if anyone cares)

[image]

With all this in place, I can now achieve my initial goal and also prepare myself for any new features that might need to leverage specific stuff on the **QueueClient** that the bindings simply don't offer at the time of writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- `await Task.Delay(n)`(task delay to simulate message processing) worked for me in Isolated Azure Functions C# Project to delay the Visibility of the message.

```c
     [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");           
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Next visible {i}: {response.ToString()}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            return response;

        }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Nice! The Task.Delay() could've worked indeed but sometimes, I need to quickly place a message in a queue and tell it to be visible in 60 minutes. I'm afraid the Task.Delay() approach could work if the delay occurs within a few minutes. I'll keep that in mind thank you :-)